# Why is the infinite (definite) integral of x^3 , divergent and not 0?

Tags: definite-integrals

Why is the integral from negative inf to positive inf of x^3 divergent? It's an odd function from -a to a, and because its odd, its symmetric about y=-x, So shouldnt all the areas cancel and get 0?

Comment: Because it depends on how you approach $\infty$ and $-\infty$.  For example, if you approach $\infty$ twice as fast as you approach $-\infty$, you won't have them cancel.  Your notion is known as the Cauchy Principal Value of the improper integral.

Comment: But we know it is symmetric, so we know +inf is approached just as fast as -inf. I agree with the last point

Comment: what the function is shouldn't at all affect the rate at which you approach your limits, so I don't see how being symmetric means "we know $+\infty$ is approached just as fast as $-\infty$"

Comment: Then I dont understand what you mean by "approach"

Comment: I think that Bruce's answer reflects what I'm trying to say.  You're pretending that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty{x^3dx}=\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}{\int_{-a}^a{x^3dx}}$, when really it is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty{x^3dx}=\lim_{(a,b)\rightarrow (-\infty,\infty)}{\int_a^b{x^3dx}}$.  If you take the path $t,2t$, then $b$ is "approaching" $\infty$ twice as fast as $a$ is "approaching" $-\infty$.  The point is that it depends upon the path you take, and hence the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

See [Why is it not true that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty{\rm} x\,dx=0 \, $ given that x is an odd function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354249/why-is-it-not-true-that-int-infty-infty-rm-x-dx-0-given-that-x-is/1354265#1354265) for a similar discussion. Everything that is said there also applies to your function, because $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for your function. The basic consensus is that the integral is undefined for various reasons, unless you define your integral to be $\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^a f(x) dx$, which is a non-traditional definition (although studied in some contexts).

Comment: But an integral is defined as the area under a curve, which we know is 0, just by looking at the graph! So, I understand how the definition of an improper integral gives a divergent answer. But the definition of an integral says it should be 0

Answer (score 2):

Following up on the comment of @user2566092:
Would you really be satisfied with a definition of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$ in which $\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^a f(x)\, dx$
gives a different answer than $\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-2a}^a f(x)\, dx$?